nextauth authorize function returning a {} before user data
so in my authorize function in nextAuth , when checking valid information of the i get a {} , then i get the user object however  and this has led to enter the opposite condition first than access the condition after r=getting user object , the api endpoint is doing well ,  i assumed that this problem has a relation to async/await function  it may return {} until it get the data , any  suggestions ?
//my credentials code
CredentialsProvider({
        name: "Credentials",
 
        credentials: {
          email: {},
          password: {}
        },
        async authorize(credentials, req) {
          // Add logic here to look up the user from the credentials supplied
try{
          // const res = await getUserCredentials(credentials?.email as string,  credentials?.password as string)
          // const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/login",{
          //   method:"POST",
          //   headers:{
          //     "Content-type":"application/json"
          //   },
          //   body:JSON.stringify({
          //     email:credentials?.email,
          //     password: credentials?.password
          //   })
          // })

          const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/login",{
            method:"POST",
            headers:{
              "Content-type":"application/json"
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
              email:credentials?.email,
              password: credentials?.password
            })
          }).then((response)=>response.text())
          .then((result)=>console.log(result))
          .catch((error)=>console.log(error))


          
    
      
        
        
        

    
        const isEmpty = (obj:any) => {
          return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
        };



 const user = await res;
console.log(user+'bbb');

        // if (!res.ok) {
        //   console.error("Invalid credentials provided");
        // return null;

        // }
        // if (res) {
        //   console.log("User authenticated:", user);
        //    console.log("this is user : " , user)
        //   return user;
        // } 
        //   console.error("User not found or invalid response:", user);
        //   return null;
        
        return null
        
       

        
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during user authentication:", error);
        return null;
      }

        }
      }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
      async jwt({ token, user }) {
    
        return { ...token, ...user };
        
      },
      async session({ session, token, user }) {
        session.user = token as any;
        return session;
      },
    },

